# Deploy an app on Heroku containing private repo in its requirements file

Tags: heroku, pip

I have a python application that contains multible private repos in its requirements.txt file via editable ssh like

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

now i want to deply this application to heroku , what is the most secure way to do so?

i have read about deploy tokens but i dont know where to put them , in heroku env or git secret or what

Comment: Strange, the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions) does not mention secrets...

Comment: Git doesn't have secrets (though a credential helper might, but that's up to the credential helper, and probably won't do much good through heroku).